# Thread pool for WSO2 ESB

Tags: tcp, wso2, threadpool, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB (for TCP/IP requests), I see only 20 TCP-worker threads being used, as I increase the concurrent requests. **Is there any way to increase number of TCP-worker threads?**

I see CPU utilization below 40%, I guess increasing TCP-worker count would lead to better cpu utilization as we increase the load. Can someone suggest, where the **thread-pool configurations** are for WSO2-ESB or how to change it.

Here is the snippet from wso2-esb-service.log

```
2015-10-20 14:49:52,852 [-] [tcp-Worker-14]  INFO 
2015-10-20 14:49:52,853 [-] [tcp-Worker-19]  INFO 
2015-10-20 14:49:52,854 [-] [tcp-Worker-6]  INFO 
2015-10-20 14:49:52,855 [-] [tcp-Worker-7]  INFO 
2015-10-20 14:49:52,856 [-] [tcp-Worker-9]  INFO 
2015-10-20 14:49:52,857 [-] [tcp-Worker-15]  INFO 
2015-10-20 14:49:52,858 [-] [tcp-Worker-2]  INFO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the values of `worker_pool_size_core` and `worker_pool_size_max` through `repository/conf/passthru-http.properties` file.

```
## Pass-through HTTP transport specific tuning parameters
worker_pool_size_core=400
worker_pool_size_max=500
#worker_thread_keepalive_sec=60
#worker_pool_queue_length=-1
#io_threads_per_reactor=2
io_buffer_size=16384
#http.max.connection.per.host.port=32767
```

Additionally you may have a look on [Performance Tuning](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Performance+Tuning) of WSO2 ESB, specially [Configuring passthru-http.properties](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Configuring+passthru-http.properties)

Comment: HI Abimaran.. I hope you are talking about  worker_pool_size_core=400
worker_pool_size_max=500 .. I thought I tried them, let me recheck though.. Thanks for taking time..

Comment: Just to be clear, I am making vanilla TCP request not http.. The properties mentioned in passthru-http.properties are applicable for TCP transport receivers too..
<transportReceiver name="tcp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportListener">
        <parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">text/plain</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6060</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

Can you please  confirm..

Comment: I did try again.. Not sure it helped. In the log I still see tcp thread limited to 20 ([tcp-Worker-6]).. Not sure which setting controls that. I changed worker_pool_size_core to 600 and max to 800.. still there is no change. It is not able to take higher TCP (please note) requests.Any clue

Comment: I think that the passthrough-http.properties are only used by the Passthrough transports. For others transports I think you need to create a properties file named after the transport name. E.g, tcp.properties. In this file you´ll create the following entries:
snd_t_core
snd_t_max
snd_alive_sec
snd_qlen,

which correspond to the server thread pool parameters. If wou want, you should take a look at the source code for the org.apache.axis2.transport.base.TransportConfiguration class,available at github

Comment: Thanks Philippe.. That was very helpful to say least.. Having said that I still couldn't make thread go beyond 20(in the log), even though snd_t_core is 35. At least is consistent with default value 20. I will be trying bit more and let you know. I copied tcp.properties into repository\conf folder. Anything else you think, I might be missing. Thanks again

Comment: Ok.. As promised.. I tried it again..tcp.properties copied into conf folder. Still only 20 tcp threads. Actually I saw in the load where tcp-thread number is getting printed and double confirmed in JMX console (console.exe). Appreciate any help to increase number of threads..  Here are the detais of tcp.properties snd_t_core=35
snd_t_max=100
snd_alive_sec=5
snd_qlen=-1

Answer (score 0):

1. `export JAVA_OPTS="-Dsnd_t_core=50”`
2. `./bin/wso2server.sh`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17161262)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong.Question:"Is there any way to increase number of TCP-worker threads?". Ans:"snd_t_core" is correct param to increase worker threads,

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following in the tcp.properties file. You will need to create the tcp.properties file in [EI_HOME]/conf directory. The following is a sample configuration to increase the TCP thread pool.

```
lst_t_core=200
lst_t_max=250
snd_t_core=200
snd_t_max=250
```